# Error on starting Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I configured Pig on my Hadoop system, but when I start it I get an error related to log4j. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

```
$ pig
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate class [org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter].
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.log.metrics.EventCounter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:179)
        ...
log4j:ERROR Could not instantiate appender named "EventCounter".
2014-02-14 10:45:46,512 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.11.1 (r1459641) compiled Mar 22 2013, 02:13:53
2014-02-14 10:45:46,513 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /usr/local/hadoop/pig_1392381946511.log
2014-02-14 10:45:46,541 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.impl.util.Utils - Default bootup file /home/hduser/.pigbootup not found
2014-02-14 10:45:46,695 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: maprfs:///
2014-02-14 10:45:46,767 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader - Loaded the native-hadoop library
2014-02-14 10:45:46,768 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping - Using JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping for Group resolution
2014-02-14 10:45:46,853 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: maprfs:///
grunt>
```

Comment: The title made me laugh.

Comment: That'll do pig, that'll do.

Comment: OP, looks like you didn't fully configure it properly.

Comment: All my configurations are at .bashrc

export PIG_HOME=/usr/lib/pig/pig-0.11.1/
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_HOME/bin

export PIG_CLASSPATH=/usr/local/hadoop/conf
export PATH=$PATH:$PIG_CLASSPATH

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/conf
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try running a pig script locally by

```
           pig -x local <filename>.pig
```

If some error message shows up for running it locally also try 
www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSsVvZnGz0M setup video,it is proper if you are using ubuntu 12.04LTS‎

Comment: I compiled again the pig (http://www.javatute.com/javatute/faces/post/hadoop/2014/installing-pig-11-for-hadoop-2-on-ubuntu-12-lts.xhtml) and I still get the same error.

Comment: please use the youtube link i gave you...and check if your $hadoop_home is set right in the pig configuration files